# Как долго будет расширяться буфер?

Tags: golang

Это стандартный метод Write() в пакете bytes

```
// Write appends the contents of p to the buffer, growing the buffer as
// needed. The return value n is the length of p; err is always nil. If the
// buffer becomes too large, Write will panic with ErrTooLarge.
func (b *Buffer) Write(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    b.lastRead = opInvalid
    m, ok := b.tryGrowByReslice(len(p))
    if !ok {
        m = b.grow(len(p))
    }
    return copy(b.buf[m:], p), nil
}
```

Правильно ли я понимаю, что данный метод будет расширять буфер и сам го не будет оповещать о раздутии буфера пока система не прекратит давать ресурс? А когда система прекратит давать ресурс, то программа просто запаникует и упадет? И какие есть "правильные" способы ограничить раздутие буфера, чтобы паники точно не было?